# PHP : How can I Match 0 and 000 (both different value) from the array

Tags: php

I am working small application. In this app I want to check the value in array which is available or not.

For example :

```
$array  = ['777',   '444',  '111',  '888',  '555',   '222',  '999',  '666',  '333',  '000']
```

If I want to check value which is available in array, I simply used `in_array` function & it returns `true` if value is available in array.

But here 0 and 000 both are different value.So I am not able to differentiate 0 and 000 value, If I search 0 it returns true which is not correct for this application.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strict` parameter to [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array) to force an exact match. In your case, because the values are all digits, the comparison is happening numerically, and so `'0' == '000'`.

```
$array  = ['777',   '444',  '111',  '888',  '555',   '222',  '999',  '666',  '333',  '000'];

echo in_array('0', $array) ? 'found' : 'not found';
echo "\n";
echo in_array('0', $array, true) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Output:

```
found
not found
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Tmhl1)

Comment: Perfect Solutions!